# Reduce speech recognition latency

Tags: python, speech-recognition

In SpeechRecognition, when I start speech recognition and speak, I'm recognized a few seconds after the end of the talk, but can't I shorten the time it takes for my words to end and become recognized?

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from speech_recognition import *
import pyaudio
import os

translator = googletrans.Translator()

r = Recognizer()
m = Microphone()

while 1 == True:
    with m as source:
        print('ready')
        audio = r.listen(source)
        Text = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print(Text)
```

Comment: Unless this library has some way to allow you to stream the audio to the service while it is being recorded, and possible stream the transcription back to you as it's being made, I don't see how. Look at the documentation for streaming features.

Comment: Drop the first import.